# Google Drive SDK Custom Permissions Role

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

I am using the latest Google Drive API to upload and convert a docx.
This docx is shared with a google drive account with the "writer" role.
The problem is that I don't want my writers to be able to share this document. And they don't have the ability to do this, however if they save a copy they can still do this and I don't want that.

Basically my question is:
Is it possible to either add custom roles to the Drive API/SDK or change independent permissions despite the applied role?

Answer (score 0):

The `labels.restricted` attribute prevents download/copy operations but only for users with reader permissions. There is no way to prevent a writer from downloading/copying. Can you restrict the account to reader permissions? Note that the account will always have *some* method to download or copy with copy/paste functionality as long as they can see the document.

Comment: I do understand that there always is a way to share this, we currently use Word to edit documents via a sky-drive like setup. And we are scouting the market to find a replacement.
I just don't feel comfortable knowing any of the writers could just create a shared folder and save all my documents as a copy so easily.
I heard a developer of Google, on the Google developers YouTube channel, talk about using the SDK for companies but if documents can be shared that easily I doubt that will happen.